Fix EFI/Microsoft in Windows 11 using Linux
I destroyed EFI/Microsoft. and Recovery Media doesn't work either. Are there any suggestions for fixing EFI/Microsoft in Linux based OS. My Windows version 11. I was going to install refind but instead I made a stupid mistake

Please explain, using specific details: how you destroyed EFI, what you tried with Recovery Media, what "refind" is and how this impacted your system. Use the EDIT button to make your question more clear. Also, please note that while Chat GPT can have its uses, it is not a trustworthy source regarding technical issues that you do not personally have a significant amount of knowledge or experience in, as you need to be able to check and correct its suggestions. In researching solutions for problems you haven't dealt with before, use real sources rather than LLM hallucinations.

For boot-repair of Windows, it's enough to do
Startup Repair in Windows 11.
This is done by booting Windows from USB and selecting Troubleshoot,
Advanced options, Startup Repair. If you're using dual-boot with
Linux, this might require under certain conditions afterward to fix
the GRUB dual-boot.
If you don't have a Windows boot media or a recovery media, you may
create one with Linux. This requires to
Download Windows 11
and use a Linux utility to copy it to the USB disk.
You should search for an article on creating the boot media from your
Linux distribution. Here is one general article:
How to Create a Windows Bootable USB on Linux.
